# ScrollView not working programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

Jest I tried programmatically `ScrollView`. It's working nice in `ViewController.m`
I tried like this

```
scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    scroll.delegate=self;
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(100, 525);
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    goo=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    goo.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 100);
    goo.backgroundColor= [UIColor brownColor];
    [goo setTitle:@"good Day" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goo addTarget:self action:@selector(ok:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [scroll addSubview:goo];
```

Working Nice but  same code is not working in `SecondViewControl`

```
-(void)ok:(id)sender
{
     Second *second=[[Second alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [second setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Second.m

```
scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        scroll.delegate=self;
        scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(100, 525);
        scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
        [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

I don't understand why `scrollView` not working in `Second.m` but same code working on `ViewControl.m.`My Xcode `Version 6.0.1`

Comment: What the meaning of "not working" ?

Comment: @KudoCC ScrollView not working means ScrollView Not Working in second ViewControl

Comment: @user3678584 What do you mean not working?? It's not visible? It's not scrolling?

Comment: @Rushi ScrollView is Visible but it's not scroll So Please tell me what working in my code

Comment: try to increase contentsize. maybe your contentsize is low then your frame.

Comment: @user3678584 scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(100, 1000); try this and see if it scrolls.

Comment: @Rushi and Chinttu -RoxeN- Ramani I tried as we said but not working,Same code working on Main.storyboard but it's not working on Second.xib, Please give me any idea

Comment: Where did you write your code viewDidLoad??

Comment: @Rushi YES - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    scroll.delegate=self;
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(100, 525);
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
   
    
}

Comment: @user3678584 :- Dear. add something in scroll view. Scroll view only works when contentsize > scrollview size... So please first add and than check. Thank you.

Comment: @user3678584 can you try to add the code in viewwillappear and check.

Comment: @PavanAlapati if my answer helps you then please mark it as a accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `presentViewController` instead of `modalViewController` and set the Delegate of `UIScrollView` to `SecondViewController`

Answer (score 0):

**Check the Following Steps:**

1. Do you conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your second class.
2. If not set , the code  `scroll.delegate=self;` will cause problem.

Comment: I set like this UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: @PavanAlapati You are right. it means you need to confirm ScrollView Delegate Protocal. Which i mentioned in step no. 1